# foreman start failed on development rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack-dev-server

I followed the **webpack-rails** gem documentation steps to install the webpacker on my rails app.

Once I ran `bundle exec rails generate webpack_rails:install` all files were generated and `foreman` was added to the gem file. Then again I did `bundle install`. After that I did

`foreman start` as stated in documentation.

Then I got this error.

```
18:54:56 rails.1   | started with pid 19096
18:54:56 webpack.1 | started with pid 19097
18:54:56 webpack.1 | /home/desmond/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/foreman-0.64.0/bin/foreman-runner: 41: exec: ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server: not found
18:54:56 webpack.1 | exited with code 127
18:54:56 system    | sending SIGTERM to all processes
18:54:56 rails.1   | terminated by SIGTERM
```

I saw a similar question here but no answer.

Comment: I think you are missing a link to the other question you saw. Did you install yarn and run `yarn install`? (I assume the gem generated a `package.json` file as well)

Comment: This `yarn` was missing. Thanx ! I thought it was installed when it prompted during webpack install. So people need to install `yarn` package inorder to get this gem working. Please add this as the answer. I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks! I added my answer with a bit more information for others who might come across this. Glad that solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gem refers to `yarn` for bundling node packages (you can also use straight npm). Per the [gem](https://github.com/mipearson/webpack-rails) tough, you need to [install yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/)  then you need to run

```
`yarn install`
```

(this step is missing from the ReadMe) to actually install the node modules needed to use webpack.

[yarn cli](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/)